# Passing a unique_ptr to a function which adds it to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I have a class that holds a vector of unique_ptr. The class also has a method to add an element to the vector.

```
class PointerVector
{
  public:
    void addPointer(std::unique_ptr<int> p);

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> mPointers;
};
```

The `addPointer` method definition:

```
void PointerVector::addPointer(std::unique_ptr<int> p)
{
  mPointers.emplace_back(std::move(p));
}
```

So I use `std::move` to transfer ownership of the pointer.

When I call `addPointer`, I also use `std::move`:

```
PointerVector pv;
std::unique_ptr<int> i(new i(1));
pv.addPointer(std::move(i));
```

Is this the correct way to do things? It feels like a hassle having to call `std::move` all the time.

**Edit**: I actually want to hold a vector of unique_ptr to a class, but I wanted to try with an int first, to make things easier.

Comment: Why do you want to hold a vector of unique_ptr to int? why not `std::vector<int> data;` ??

Comment: I actually want to hold a vector of unique_ptr to a class, but I wanted to try with an int first, to make things easier.

Comment: Is `std::unique_ptr` an important part of the interface or an implementation detail ?

Comment: It's an implementation detail. That's why I didn't like having to use it outside of the `PointerVector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost. You don't need to use `std::move()` when passing a temporary, your last fragment would look better as below (I am not asking why you need to store a smart pointer to an int rather than an int itself).

```
PointerVector pv;
pv.addPointer(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)));
```

Comment: What if I want to store a more complex type? For example: make an object of a `Person` class, set the person's name, and *then* add it? Would it be best like this? `PointerVector pv; Person* p = new Person(); p->setName("John"); pv.addPointer(std::unique_ptr<Person>(p));`

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp - with more complex data type when initialization is done not only via constructor I would indeed do `std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person); ...; pv.addPointer(std::move(p));`, details matter :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `emplace_back` to construct a new `unique_ptr<int>` element directly in the right place at the end of your vector, maybe the simplest solution is to let your `PointerVector` class encapsulate the whole `unique_ptr` management logic and just give it a raw pointer:

```
class PointerVector
{
  public:
    void addPointer(int* p);

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> mPointers;
};


void PointerVector::addPointer(int* p) {
     assert(nullptr != p);
     mPointers.emplace_back(p);
}

PointerVector pv;
pv.addPointer(new int(1));
```